# loading zombie js driver properly for Mink and php

Tags: php, node.js, centos6, mink, zombie.js

I have managed installing node.js v0.12.2 and npm 2.7.4 on Centos 6.

In the directory `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` I now have two directories that created automatically:

npm

zombie

So I have used the linux command `export PATH_NODE="/usr/local/lib/node_modules"`, but whenever I run the below script, I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Server process has been terminated: (8) [ module.js:340 throw err; ^ Error: Cannot find module 'zombie' at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15) at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25) at Module.require (module.js:364:17) at require (module.js:380:17) at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/mink_nodejs_serverddCfA0:2:16) at Module._compile (module.js:456:26) at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10) at Module.load (module.js:356:32) at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12) at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10) ]' in /home/birdsnest/public_html/test/vendor/behat/mink-zombie-driver/src/Behat/Mink/Driver/NodeJS/Server.php:406 Stack trace: #0 /home/birdsnest/public_html/test/vendor/behat/mink-zombie-driver/src/Behat/Mink/Driver/NodeJS/Server.php(302): Behat\Mink\Driver\NodeJS\Server->checkAvailability() #1
```

script:

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';


$driver = new \Behat\Mink\Driver\ZombieDriver(
    new \Behat\Mink\Driver\NodeJS\Server\ZombieServer()
);

// init session:
$session = new \Behat\Mink\Session($driver);

// start session:
$session->start();

// open some page in browser:
$session->visit('website');

// get the current page URL:
echo $session->getCurrentUrl();

// get the response status code:
echo $session->getStatusCode();

// get page content:
//echo $session->getPage()->getContent();

// evaluate JS expression:
echo $session->evaluateScript(
    "return 'something from browser';"
);

?>
```

I have done a lot of research and tried many possible solutions, but still unable to get it working. Any help would be appreciated :)

update:

When going into the directory: /vendor/behat/mink-zombie-driver/src/Behat/Mink/Driver/NodeJS/Server.php

on line 81 of the Server.php file, I have updated the `$nodeModulesPath = '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/'`

But the error is then:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Server process has been terminated: (8) [ /usr/local/lib/node_modules/zombie/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:83 throw e ^ Error: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/zombie/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify/build/Release/contextify.node: undefined symbol: node_module_register at Module.load (module.js:356:32) at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12) at Module.require (module.js:364:17) at require (module.js:380:17) at bindings (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/zombie/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:76:44) at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/zombie/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify/lib/contextify.js:1:96) at Module._compile (module.js:456:26) at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10) at Module.load (module.js:356:32) at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12) at Module.requ in /home/birdsnest/public_html/test/vendor/behat/mink-zombie-driver/src/Behat/Mink/Driver/NodeJS/Server.php on line 406
```